# Vuetify - Changing v-tabs via key

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a vuetify tab component which includes a menu and a lot of different tabs which can show up in a random order. It seems like the v-tab toggling works via index-based. How can a vuetify v-tab be toggled to the correct tab via key/unique Id?

Example:

```
 <v-tabs v-model="tab">
   <v-tab href="#tab-myUniqueKeyOne">TEST ONE</v-tab>
   <v-menu>
     <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
       <v-btn text v-on="on">DROPDOWN_TAB</v-btn>
     </template>
     <v-list>
       <v-list-item @click="changeToTab('tab-foo')">Foo</v-list-item>
       <v-list-item @click="changeToTab('tab-bar')">Bar</v-list-item>
     </v-list>
   </v-menu>
   <v-tab href="#tab-myUniqueKeyThree">TEST THREE</v-tab>
   <v-tab href="#tab-myUniqueKeyTwo">TEST TWO</v-tab>
 </v-tabs>
 <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
   <v-tab-item value="tab-foo">My Foo</v-tab-item>
   <v-tab-item value="tab-baz">Some Hidden Tab</v-tab-item>
   <v-tab-item value="tab-myUniqueKeyTwo">Two</v-tab-item>
   <v-tab-item value="tab-bar">My Bar</v-tab-item>
   <v-tab-item value="tab-myUniqueKeyThree">Three</v-tab-item>
   <v-tab-item value="tab-myUniqueKeyOne">One</v-tab-item>
 </v-tabs-items>

 data: () => {
   tab: null,
 }
 methods: {
   changeToTab(tab) {
     this.tab = tab;
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should remove `-key` from `</v-tab-item-key>`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo from psuedo-code.  The code above seems to work for v-tab, but does not for the v-menus v-list-items.  When they are clicked the screen briefly ( a few milliseconds) flashes the correct tab over top of the default start tab and then the correct tab disappears

Comment: i copy/paste your code [here](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/jONGdwG?editors=1010) and it seems work fine, where's the issue exactly? could make a screenshot?

Comment: I forgot to put the menu button in the OP. They are in there now. If you add the template/button code into your example you will see the dropdown tab as a tab option. Clicking on the menu items will not bring up the correct pages.

Comment: that dropdown should be placed inside `v-tab-item` like https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/jONGdwG?editors=1010

Comment: No, that places it in the wrong location. It is considered a 'tab' according to the vuetify docs to do it as I posted. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs#with-menu

Comment: like [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs#with-menu)?

Comment: Yeah, we're talking about the same example. However I cannot get their example to work with the post I made. Possibly because theirs is using indexing and not keys, and their menu is at the end.

Comment: It looks like the issue still exists if everything is in the same order.  I have no idea what's different between this and the example on their page. https://codepen.io/uglyhobbitfeet/pen/NWKaQGZ?editors=1010

Answer (score 5):

Below is a simplified example. Bottom line, use `href` in the `tabs` and `value` in `tab-items`

https://codepen.io/jack3625/pen/xxwopad

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only way to get this working is to also create a tab for each menu item and hide it.

```
<v-tab href="#tab-foo" style="display:none">FOO</v-tab>
<v-tab href="#tab-bar" style="display:none">BAR</v-tab>
```

Full example shown here:
https://codepen.io/uglyhobbitfeet/pen/NWKaQGZ?editors=1010

Comment: I presume this is what you want: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs#with-menu